# Нарисовать трехмерный, разноцветный, движущийся куб

Tags: android, 3d, java, opengl

Здравтвуйте! Пытаюсь нарисовать трехмерный, разноцветный, движущийся куб. Но получается вот что(GL_TRIANGLES_FAN):

[image]

(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)

[image]

Как я понимаю: определяем координаты вершин фигуры, указываем индексы и цвета. 
Все это загоняем в `ByteBuffer`, в данном случае, определяем сколько памяти нам нужно.
И в методе `onDrawFrame`: 
 Указываем начальную позицию фигуры на сцене:

```
gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -5);
```

Указываем способ, по которому будут строиться треугольники:

```
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, cube.length);
```

GL_TRIANGLE _FAN — Треугольники задаются первой и каждой следующей парой вершин (пары не пересекаются).
Вот... Обычный 2д квадрат у меня получился. Подскажите, где  я ошибся.

```
public class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int i, int i2) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, i, i2);

        float ratio = (float) i / i2;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);
    }

/**
 * Vertices coordinates
 */
    float [] cube = {
            0, 0, -1,  // A
            1, 0, -1,  // B
            1, 0, 1,  // C
            0, 0, 1,  // D

            0, 1, -1,  // E
            1, 1, -1,  // F
            1, 1, 1,  // G
            0, 1, 1   // H
    };

    float colors[] = {
            0, 0, 0, 1,  //0  black
            1, 0, 0, 1,  //1  red
            1, 1, 0, 1,  //2  yellow
            0, 1, 0, 1,  //3  green
            0, 0, 1, 1,  //4  blue
            1, 0, 1, 1,  //5  magneta
            1, 1, 1, 1,  //6  white
            0, 1, 1, 1,  //7  cyan
    };

byte [] index = {0,4,5,
                 1,5,6,
                 2,6,7,
                 3,7,4,
                 4,7,6,
                 3,0,1
};
    FloatBuffer cubeBuffer;
    FloatBuffer colorBuffer;
    ByteBuffer indexBuffer;

    public Renderer() {

        ByteBuffer bb1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(cube.length*4);
        bb1.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        cubeBuffer = bb1.asFloatBuffer();
        cubeBuffer.put(cube);
        cubeBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer cb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length*4);
        cb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        colorBuffer = cb.asFloatBuffer();
        colorBuffer.put(colors);
        colorBuffer.position(0);

        indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(index.length*4);
        indexBuffer.put(index);
        indexBuffer.position(0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);
        gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -5);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, cubeBuffer);
        //gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, index.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, cube.length);
        gl.glRotatef(1, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    }
```

Comment: indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(index.length*4);

Почему 4, а не 1? Или в конце концов может лучше int вместо byte в массиве индексов?

Comment: @MDJHD, спасибо, подправлю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень достойная статья для начинающих по OpenGL ES2 http://dedfox.com/izuchaem-opengl-es2-pod-android-urok-1-samoe-nachalo/

Минимальный (можно убрать проверку поддержки ES2 для еще большего минимализма) каркас по этой статье набрал, просто инициализация OpenGL ES2 с отрисовкой GLSurfaceView с серым фоном:

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ConfigurationInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private GLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);

        // Проверка поддержки OpenGL ES2 устройством
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ConfigurationInfo ci = am.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
        // 0х20000 - старшие 16 бит обозначают первое число версии, младшие второе (2.0)
        if(ci.reqGlEsVersion < 0x20000) 
        {
            this.finish();
        }

        // Установим контекст OpenGL ES2
        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        // Установим рендерер
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new MyRenderer());

        setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
    }
}
```

MyRenderer.java

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;

public class MyRenderer implements Renderer
{
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
    {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
    {
        // Устанавливаем фоновый цвет
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Еще гляньте здесь: http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=418429

Answer (score 2):

Прошу прощения, код не компилировал, да и взглянул довольно бегло, но первое, что точно нужно поправить - рисовать GL_TRIANGLES, а не GL_TRIANGLES_STRIP и уж тем более GL_TRIANGLES_FAN.

Насчет режимов хотелось бы рассказать поподробнее. Предположим, у Вас такой индексный буфер: {a, b, c, d, e, f}. Так вот, в первом режиме, который Вам и нужен(GL_TRIANGLES), отрисуется два треугольника - abc и def. Во втором - abc,bcd,cde,def (этакая цепочка. Нужно для оптимизации.). В третьем - abc,acd,ade,aef (веер, то есть первая вершина общая для всех треугольников. Удобно для рисования выпуклых многоугольников)

ЗЫ: Рекомендую сразу осваивать OpenGL ES 2.0. Он немного сложнее, зато гораздо более гибкий, производительный и перспективный(OpenGL ES 3.0 - расширение для 2.0, в то время как 1.0 практически не используется уже достаточно давно)

Comment: А у меня используется 1.0 ? Примеров не подкините, где код можно посмотреть и вообще доки/туториалы по ES 2.0/3.0

Comment: Да, конечно - у Вас же написано - "public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)". OpenGL ES 2/3 реализован как статический класс, ну и называется, соответственно, GLES20/GLES30
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html - я по этому официальному туториалу осваивал. Наверняка, впрочем, можно найти множество полноценных уроков, да и на русском должны быть.